How do I route an IP address "into" a WireGuard tunnel?
I have two machines A and B. A is a VPS that has globally routable IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, B is a physical server behind a carrier-grade NAT:

A:

IPv4 addresses A1 and A2 (on-link);
IPv6 prefix A3::/56 (routed).


B only has an IPv4 address B1 in the RFC 6598 100.64.0.0/10 address block.


A and B are on different networks, different ISPs, nothing in common except that A1 and A2 are reachable from B.

I need to configure a tunnel between A and B, such that B would behave as if A2 is its address.
Specifically, I need to be able to:

receive connections to A2 on machine B,
initiate new connections using A2 from machine B, and
perform DNAT on some of the incoming connections and redirect them to other machines C1..Cn that are "behind" B.

How do I do that?

Most tunnels can handle it in the same way, but start with setting up a WireGuard tunnel purely because it's UDP-based and is more likely to go through (CG)NAT than e.g. raw GRE. (Alternatively, GRE-over-IPsec would also work as IPsec will automatically use UDP encapsulation, giving you GRE-ESP-UDP. I believe L2TP and VXLAN can also work fine, both being UDP-based.)
Also, having some kind of keepalive will be necessary due to (CG)NAT otherwise losing track of idle flows, and WireGuard's built-in "PersistentKeepalive" will be handy. Enable the sending of keepalive packets from B (on the [Peer] representing A), as it's the one that needs to "punch out".

Once you have the tunnel up:
For the IP address, routing to B is straightforward; you literally route that address through the tunnel interface.
It's more important to make B route replies through that tunnel as well. This is best done using "policy routing" if B is capable of that, though SNAT on A (as seen in "NAT hairpin" situations) can be used in a pinch. (Linux also implements a third easier option, source-specific routes, but only for IPv6; not for IPv4.)
"On-link" means the original server still needs to answer ARP queries for A2, there is no other difference. If A2 isn't directly assigned to an interface on A, then A needs to answer on its behalf anyway (proxy ARP).

Deassign A2 from any of A's interfaces.
Enable proxy ARP for A2 using ip neigh add ... proxy. (Or the parpd daemon if you prefer; whichever is easier to configure.)Unfortunately, systemd-networkd's [Neighbor] will not work to replace 'ip neigh add' – it is still missing the equivalent of 'proxy' flag.Note: I would not suggest using the "blanket enable" proxy_arp or IPv4ProxyARP= sysctls – they're a bit too broad and you don't want to accidentally proxy A's whole network back to itself.
Verify with tcpdump that A still responds ARP queries for A2, e.g. when A2 is pinged from outside and A's upstream gateway tries to make the ARP query. tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 'arp'
Route A2/32 via wg0. If using wg-quick, it will do this automatically according to AllowedIPs in the next step.
Update wg0 "AllowedIPs" on A to internally route A2/32 to the [Peer] representing B (which also causes A to accept packets "from A2" from that peer).
Verify with tcpdump that packets for A2 leave through A's wg0.
Update wg0 "AllowedIPs" on B to 0.0.0.0/0 on the peer representing A, both to accept packets from any source and to internally route packets for any destination. Don't reload config yet (if you don't have physical console access).
Assuming wg-quick is being used, update B's wg0 configuration to have "Table" set to a currently unused route table ID. Verify with ip route list table X that it has a 0.0.0.0/0 route via wg0 (corresponding to AllowedIPs). If wg-quick isn't being used, add that route manually instead.
Verify with tcpdump that packets to A2 arrive at B's wg0. This has to be done after AllowedIPs.
Assign A2/32 to B's wg0 interface (or any other of B's interfaces).
Add a policy-routing rule on B to select table X for any packet with A2 as source. For example, ip rule add from A2/32 lookup X or systemd-networkd's [RoutingPolicyRule].
Verify with tcpdump that B is now replying to pings and that those replies are going out through its wg0.
Verify with tcpdump that A is receiving those replies through its wg0 and forwarding them out through the WAN interface towards the pinger.
B can now do whatever it wants with the packets.

The steps would be very similar for any tunnel type, e.g. GRE, minus the "AllowedIPs" business (GRE or IPIP only have a single peer so they automatically allow any address), and minus the related automatic routes (create them manually instead).
An alternative process without proxy-ARP is also possible, where A2 remains assigned to A, but A does a blanket DNAT to B's tunnel address. This does not let B "own" A2, but nevertheless it is very common as seen in e.g. Big Cloud Providers (GCE, EC2, Oracle) which implement "floating IPs" in exactly this way, and also seen in home gateways which call it "DMZ". It still allows B to route/DNAT the packets further.

Thanks! This answers almost every question I had about this setup.
Just one thing: which interface would be "best" to use on B as the "transplant host"? I understand that "any" means "any", but I can imagine various issues with other interfaces' lifecycles interfering with this address assignment, e.g. if I assign it to the WAN interface and it goes down temporarily, the address will disappear, etc. Is it possible to create a dummy interface that is not connected to anything? Or maybe I could add A2 directly to wg0?

Since packets for this address arrive only through wg0 (no dynamic routing involved), assigning the address to wg0 would be most appropriate – it would pretty much mirror the standard setup where the eth0 address is on the eth0 interface, etc. ('lo' would be my second choice). If your goal is exclusively to route or DNAT those packets somewhere further, without B ever using them directly, the address doesn't need to be assigned anywhere at all.
